# How to make a pagination loop that scrapes specific amount of pages ( pages vary from day to day)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination, python-requests-html

## Summary

I am working on my Supply Chain Management college project and want to analyze daily postings on a website to analyze and document industry's demand for services/products. Particular page that is being changed every day and with different amount of containers and pages :

https://buyandsell.gc.ca/procurement-data/search/site?f%5B0%5D=sm_facet_procurement_data%3Adata_data_tender_notice&f%5B1%5D=dds_facet_date_published%3Adds_facet_date_published_today

## Bacground

Code generates csv file ( do not mind headers) by scraping the HTML tags and documenting data points. Tried to use 'for' loop but code still scans only first page.

Python Knowledge level : Beginner, learn the 'hard-way' through youtube and googling. Found example that worked for my level of understanding but have troubles with combining people's different solutions.

## Code at the moment

import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

## problem starts here

```
for page in range (1,3):my_url = 'https://buyandsell.gc.ca/procurement-data/search/site?f%5B0%5D=sm_facet_procurement_data%3Adata_data_tender_notice&f%5B1%5D=dds_facet_date_published%3Adds_facet_date_published_today'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"rc"})
```

## this part does not write in addition to existing line items

```
filename = "BuyandSell.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "Title, Publication Date, Closing Date, GSIN, Notice Type, Procurement Entity\n"
f.write(headers)
```

```
for container in containers:
    Title = container.h2.text

    publication_container = container.findAll("dd",{"class":"data publication-date"})
    Publication_date = publication_container[0].text

    closing_container = container.findAll("dd",{"class":"data date-closing"})
    Closing_date = closing_container[0].text

    gsin_container = container.findAll("li",{"class":"first"})
    Gsin = gsin_container[0].text

    notice_container = container.findAll("dd",{"class":"data php"})
    Notice_type = notice_container[0].text

    entity_container = container.findAll("dd",{"class":"data procurement-entity"})
    Entity = entity_container[0].text

    print("Title: " + Title)
    print("Publication_date: " + Publication_date)
    print("Closing_date: " + Closing_date)
    print("Gsin: " + Gsin)
    print("Notice: " + Notice_type)
    print("Entity: " + Entity)

    f.write(Title + "," +Publication_date + "," +Closing_date + "," +Gsin + "," +Notice_type + "," +Entity +"\n")

f.close()
```

## Please let me know if you would like to see further. Rest is defining data containers that are getting found in HTML code and getting printed to csv.Any help/advice would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Actual Results :

Code generates CSV file only for the first page.

Code does not write on top of what was already scanned ( from day to day ) at least

Expected Results :

Code scans next pages and recognizes when there are no pages to go through.

CSV file would generate 10 csv lines per page. ( And whatever amount would be on the last page, as the number is not always 10).

Code would write on top of what was already scraped ( for more advanced analytics using Excel tools with historic data)

Comment: first thing I notice is `f = open(filename, "w")`. When you use mode `w`, it will overwrite. Since you want to append to an existing data, you'd want to change that to `a`. Second, you need to iterate through the pages then write those. As of now, it doesn't look like you are going from one page html, to the next. I wish there was an API to do this, but looks like it'll be the brute force. I'll work on it to help you out

Comment: Thank you chitown88! Would you like me to post the rest of the code? ( specification of containers to be found and written to csv )

Comment: oh yes. that would be helpful

Comment: Post is updated. See above. Thank you!

Comment: I went ahead and did it without that, so you can go back if you'd like and alter/change mine

Comment: I am sorry, go back where? Not sure if I understand what I can alter/change.

Comment: Sorry, just posted it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some might say using pandas is overkill, but personally I'm comfortable using it and just like using it to create tables and write to file.

there also probably a bit of a more robust way to go page to page, but I just wanted to get this to you and you can work with it.

As of now, I just hard code in the next page value (and I just arbitrarily picked 20 pages as a max.) So it's start with page 1, and then go through 20 pages (or stop once it gets to an invalid page).

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

filename = "BuyandSell.csv"

# Initialize an empty 'results' dataframe
results = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterarte through the pages
for page in range(0,20):
    url = 'https://buyandsell.gc.ca/procurement-data/search/site?page=' + str(page) + '&f%5B0%5D=sm_facet_procurement_data%3Adata_data_tender_notice&f%5B1%5D=dds_facet_date_published%3Adds_facet_date_published_today'

    page_html = requests.get(url).text
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"rc"})

    # Get data from each container
    if containers != []:
        for each in containers:
            title = each.find('h2').text.strip()
            publication_date = each.find('dd', {'class':'data publication-date'}).text.strip()
            closing_date = each.find('dd', {'class':'data date-closing'}).text.strip()
            gsin = each.find('dd', {'class':'data gsin'}).text.strip()
            notice_type = each.find('dd', {'class':'data php'}).text.strip()
            procurement_entity = each.find('dd', {'data procurement-entity'}).text.strip()

            # Create 1 row dataframe
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[title, publication_date, closing_date, gsin, notice_type, procurement_entity]], columns = ['Title', 'Publication Date', 'Closing Date', 'GSIN', 'Notice Type', 'Procurement Entity'])

            # Append that row to a 'results' dataframe
            results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
        print ('Aquired page ' + str(page+1))

    else:
        print ('No more pages')
        break


# If already have a file saved
if os.path.isfile(filename):

    # Read in previously saved file
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    # Append the newest results
    df = df.append(results).reset_index()

    # Drop and duplicates (incase the newest results aren't really new)
    df = df.drop_duplicates()

    # Save the previous file, with appended results
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)

else:

    # If a previous file not already saved, save a new one
    df = results.copy()
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: Chitown88, thank you very much. Partially makes sense as I am looking at it. I will try to work with it and comeback in case I have more questions. Really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: cool. make sure to accept the answer if it satisified your needs

Comment: How do I do that? :)

Comment: by the up and down triangles (with the big 0) by my solution. There should be a check mark or something like that that allows you to accept the answer

Comment: Hello @chitown88 - Code works perfect, thank you for your help. One supplementary question - How would I add a function that allows me to use credentials for automated login into websites that require credentials? Should I post this under the new question? Please let me know.

Comment: There's a couple ways that come to mind: Depending on the site, 1) Use some type of way to simulate the login, ie. Selenuim (this seems to work more often than not, but sometimes not the optimal way as it can sometimes be relatively slow) or 2) Sometimes you can include that as a parameter in a `requests` `GET` or `POST`. It is a good quest, and yes, I would post that as anew question. If I get a chance I'll look at it, but if you can post as a new question, you'll get a lot more eyes on it than here because will see this questions as "solved" or "answered"